# Regex: Allow minimum alphanumeric, dot and - characters. Asterisk allowed anywhere?

Tags: java, regex

My requirement is that:

1. String should contain minimum 4 characters (only alphanumeric,
   dot and hyphen allowed).
2. Apart from this asterisk is allowed anywhere (start, in-between or end)
3. It should not contain any other characters than mentioned in point 1 and 2 above.

e.g. following are valid strings:

```
Ab*08

*.6-*N*
```

following are invalid strings:

```
****AB-*

GH.*
```

My regex looks like:

```
^(.*?[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]){4,}.*$
```

My basic validations as mentioned in point 1 and 2 are working. But regex allows other special characters like <, >, & etc. How can I modify my regex to achieve this?

Comment: `.` matches any char but line break chars. Besides, your requirements are not clear. Please explain why this or that input is invalid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: As I mentioned 3 points in my question. My string should contain minimum 4 characters from (alphanumeric, dot or hyphen). String can then also contain asterisk anywhere. Apart from these characters it should not contain any other characters. in order to explain this, I gave few examples.

Comment: Why are `****AB-*` and `GH.*` invalid? Why are the other two strings valid?

Comment: Do you have to do it all in a regex? It would be much easier to check if it matches `[\.\-\*a-zA-Z0-9]*`, and check the "length" requirement separately looping thorugh characters

Comment: @RC.: I have already done basic job isn't it? I am stuck at last point and I am not so good at regex. Thus I asked this question. Rather than sarcastic comments, I would appreciate some help here. And I have asked specific issue in last line of my question. If my question does not follow SO guidelines, kindly let me know. I will modify my question accordingly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user613114 I suggest you remove the asterisks and then run a regular expression check on the resulting string. It will be a lot simpler that way.

Comment: I think Deltharis explained the mystery: `*` should not be considered when counting. Try `^(?=(?:\**[a-zA-Z0-9.-]){4})[a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+$`

Comment: @Deltharis: Many thanks for feedback. I have also in my mind that I can use separate regex to check if my string contains special characters other than allowed one. If not only go for second check for allowed characters using my regex. But its two step check. I was wondering if single regex can do that.

Comment: I think the core thing about regexes: you dont solve every problem with them. And every time you need somebody else to create that regex for you; chances are that you look out for a solution that *you* do not understand. The regex will become **your** responsibility when you add it to **your** code. So, at least for me; every time when I think "hmm, I could do this with one regex"; but I am really uneasy to build that myself; I look out for other options ;-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I love your regex101 links; I keep forgetting how easy one can use them. Send you some badge-upvotes to say thanks ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat: Thank you. Also, [here is one](https://regex101.com/r/IImtMh/1)  to demo my above regex. Actually, in Java, I guess, I'd use `\p{Alnum}` for `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Unfortunately, regex101.com still does not support Java regex flavor.

Comment: @GhostCat: Your comment regarding keeping code easy to understand rather than using complex regex, sounds like words or wisdom to me :) I will NOT use single regex.. Thanks!

Comment: Still, kewl question, so a p1 from me. And I can even live with the fact that my answer was wrong; and i had to delete it instead of collecting tons and tons of upvotes for it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[*]*[a-zA-Z0-9.-]){4}[*a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$
```

It checks for 4 valid characters (that might be surrounded by `*`) and checks that your whole string only of your required characters.

[Obligatory regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/EhsRTa/1)

Note: regex101 doesn't fully support java regex syntax. The pattern shown is a PCRE pattern, but all features used are also available in java regex.

Note2: if you use `.matches` to check your input, you can omit anchors, at it is already anchored.

Comment: That does the trick, I salute you. However, trying to match a String where asterisks have been replaced by empty char feels like a more satisfactory (and readable/maintainable) solution.

Comment: This will fail, when more than 4 characters are contained in the string to test.

Comment: @Waxolunist it properly matches `ABCDEFG.----******` so not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @SebastianProske: Your regex works as expected in this question :) Many thanks for your time!!!

Comment: @Waxolunist: Can you please give us some example strings, where this regex does not work?

Comment: Ok, now I see it. My fault. Rather complicated though having the characters twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\**[\w\d.-]\**){4,}$
```

This should do it. A little bit simpler.