# Regex 4 characters and 1 space minimum anywhere position

Tags: regex

I've tried this

```
(?!\sa-zA-Z){4,}\s{1,}
```

- I want 4 or more characters and minimum 1 space anywhere in string, but doesn't work
- The space can be anywhere position without from start.
  I've try this, but that not work
  [Regex: Allow minimum alphanumeric, dot and - characters. Asterisk allowed anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531510/regex-allow-minimum-alphanumeric-dot-and-characters-asterisk-allowed-anywhe)

EDIT: I would like this result :
aa aa..., aaa a..., a aaa..., aaaa ...

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there few example what should and what shouldn't match?

Comment: Like this? `\b[a-zA-Z](?=[a-zA-Z ]{3})[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]*` https://regex101.com/r/YUDXxp/1

Comment: @AndrejKesely like this ;)

Comment: @Thefourthbird thx, this work with \b[a-zA-Z](?=[a-zA-Z ]{4})[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]* thanks you, can you post the answer after for validate it and solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[a-zA-Z](?=[a-zA-Z ]{3})[a-zA-Z]* +[a-zA-Z]*
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a single char a-zA-Z
- `(?=[a-zA-Z ]{3})` Positive lookahead, assert 3 of the listed chars in the character class to the right of the current position
- `[a-zA-Z]* +[a-zA-Z]*` Match optional chars a-zA-Z, then match 1+ spaces space and again optional chars a-zA-Z

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgbVSm/1).